# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table (Symfony)

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hello to all I'm having a trouble about a doctrine's query.
Query is very simple and is managed like that:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;

    class ProductController extends FOSRestController
    {
        /**
         * @Rest\Get("/product")
         */
        public function getAction()
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $restresult = $em->getRepository(Product::class)->findAll();
            if ($restresult == null) {
                return new View("there are no products exist", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
            }
            return $restresult;
        }
    }
```

And Repo file is:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
        $sql = "SELECT p.productName from Product as p ";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Instead config file is:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        unix_socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
        server_version: '5.5'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

but when I execute the query, Symfony give me this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.idUser AS idUser_1, t0.email AS email_2, t0.username AS username_3, t0.password AS password_4 FROM User t0 INNER JOIN user_has_product ON t0.idUser = user_has_product.User_idUser WHERE user_has_product.Product_idProduct = ?' with params [1]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'projectKobe.user_has_product' doesn't exist

I can't understand how to resolve this problem and why the query is not: "SELECT p.productName FROM Product as p". I don't made any inner join. Thanks

Comment: And also, I type php bin/console doctrine:query:sql 'SELECT * FROM Product'. Query works fine

Comment: the code you show and the exception query seems really different ! In your code you are querying **Product**, in the exception it's **User**.Are you sure it's the correct query in fault?

Comment: can you please paste your entity class

Answer (score 1):

It's related to ORM, so Try to update your database schema.

You can check the documentation here

Official doc  [Native SQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql)

KNP university example [Doctrine Raw SQL Queries](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/raw-sql-queries)

Comment: I have just type this: php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force.
But the error is the same

Comment: i guess table name should be lowercase product

Comment: Product table in db is called: "Product". So query should be fine, indeed if I execute  php bin/console doctrine:query:sql 'SELECT * FROM Product' it works. but I do not explain how the query change when I execute it in code

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql did try using DQL

Comment: or using Doctrine query builder https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder

Comment: Nothing. The "Strange" query is the same

Comment: if you closely look this matter then you will see doctrine searching for db "projectKobe" and table  "user_has_product" instead of "Product".

Comment: what was the prob?

Comment: In Product entity there is no mapping with repo file. I have to add @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository") that string in order to solve problem and use ProductRepository.php to make queries. findAll() a own method so, if you don't overwrite it, query result "strange"